# How to append multiple element into a parent element?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, innerhtml, appendchild, queryselector

I don't understand why in the output I have just one li element, I should have 10 li inside ul.

```
 function setTodolist() {
      let ul = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
      let li = document.createElement('li');

        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ul.appendChild(li).innerText = 'Hello World';
       }
 }
  setTodolist()
```

Comment: You need to create a separate `<li>` for each of those 10 iterations.

Comment: You're appending the same element. Move your `createElement("li")` inside the loop

Comment: Thansks, I'm so stupid